# Android: Showing a toast for it's full duration upon Fragment's redraw - where in the lifecycle should it show()?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-toast

I have a `Fragment` inside it's own `Activity` designed to be triggered via an `intent` which allows for the use of `startActivityForResult`, the current use case is to edit an entry in a `ListView` and works perfectly well, but do let me know if I'm using the wrong pattern. The originating `Activity` checks data during it's `onActivityResult` and may decide there is something unacceptable (e.g. the entry would not be considered unique), in which case it fires off a new `Intent` for the same 'editing' `Activity` using the same data it received while adding an entry to the extended data with a descriptive reason (e.g. "Name already in use"); if this field exists then the 'editing' `Fragment` should display a `Toast` with that message. I have tried displaying the `Toast` at various points in the`Fragment's` start-up hierarchy of it's lifecycle - all the way up to the `onResume`, which I believe, from the docs, is last - but again correct me if I am wrong. On my real S4 it looks fine, but if I run it on a slow emulator the toast flicks in for much less than a second (it's got `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` so should last 2 seconds), so it seems to be being created *before* the view has actually been redrawn.

I could, in my current use case, change the model to pass the data against which checks should be made as a part of the original `Intent`, but this seems wrong to me - maybe that data will be large, or not yet available or maybe the 'editor' `Activity` is one that is to be generic, in which case it certainly should not have code handling cases for different callers.

So, where should the `Toast's` `show` method be called such that the user will actually be guaranteed to see it for it's full duration?

*Note: I'm pretty sure this question does not actually need code, as someone with experience should be able to just say where in the lifecyle the correct location would be, and if I make a button which shows a toast when clicked then it does display for the full 2 seconds on the same emulator - but if necessary I could probably knock up a trimmed down example.*

**EDIT** OK, here is some example code. Note that I am using json currently but will make my objects Parcelable at some point (I'm an Android and Java n00b so had not read about that until I was further into my implementation - so it's on my TODO list).

The PlayersFragment (containing an Adapter on the list of Player objects) has these methods

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int index, long id) {
        edit(index, myActivity.getPlayer(index), "");
    }
};

private void edit(int index, Player toEdit, String toastMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity, PlayerEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra(PLAYERS_INDEX, index);
    intent.putExtra(JSON_PLAYER, gson.toJson(toEdit));
    if (!toastMessage.equals("")) { intent.putExtra(TOAST_MESSAGE, toastMessage); }
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EDIT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        int playerIndex = intent.getIntExtra(PLAYERS_INDEX, -1);
        int size = myActivity.getPlayersSize();
        if (intent.hasExtra(PLAYERS_INDEX) && playerIndex >= 0 && playerIndex <= size) {
            Player player = gson.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra(JSON_PLAYER),
                    new TypeToken<Player>(){}.getType());
            if (playerIndex == size) { // A new player was created and saved or deleted
                if (player != null) { // new but null implies deleted - nothing needs to be done
                    if (myActivity.addPlayer(player)) {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        playerListView.setSelection(playerIndex);
                    } else {
                        edit(playerIndex, player, "Player name already in use");
                    }
                }
            } else { // a player was selected for edit and saved or deleted
                if (myActivity.setPlayer(playerIndex, player)) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    edit(playerIndex, player, "Player name already in use.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_players, container, false);
    playerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerList);
    playerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    playerListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    ImageButton btnPlayerAdd = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayerAdd);
    btnPlayerAdd.setOnClickListener(OnClickListenerBtnPlayerAdd);
    return view;
}

View.OnClickListener OnClickListenerBtnPlayerAdd = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // When adding a new player we go straight to the editor with a new player and an index
        // one greater than currently exists (i.e. the ArrayList's size).
        Player player = new Player();
        int index = myActivity.getPlayersSize();
        edit(index, player, "");
    }
};
```

The PlayerEditor Activity then has this method:

```
private void returnToSender() {
    //TODO: can this just be Intent()?
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PLAYERS_INDEX, playersIndex);
    if (player == null) { intent.putExtra(JSON_PLAYER, ""); }
    else { intent.putExtra(JSON_PLAYER, gson.toJson(player)); }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

The PlayerEditorFragment, inside the PlayerEditor Activity, then has:

```
View.OnClickListener OnClickListenerBtnSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String chips = ((TextView) view.getRootView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.playerEditorChipsValue)).getText().toString();
            if (chips.equals("")) { chips = "0"; }
            playerEditor.player.setChips(new BigInteger(chips));
            String name = ((TextView) view.getRootView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.playerEditorNameValue)).getText().toString();
            playerEditor.player.setName(name);
            playerEditor.returnToSender();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener  OnClickListenerBtnDelete = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playerEditor.player = null;
            playerEditor.returnToSender();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (playerEditor.toastMessage != null) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), playerEditor.toastMessage
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

- the code in onResume is what I'm not sure where to place, as I said it seems OK when I run it on my device, but running it on a slow emulator seems to expose the fact that the displayed duration could be far less than the 2 second default of Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.

**EDIT 2**
My plan for this now is to move my application's data to an Application instance rather than the main activity (which was always wrong) and only pass the index of the object in the ArrayList via intent; this way the Editor can perform checks itself; or in more complex scenarios ask the app to perform the check.
This means the toast wont ever need to be triggered upon a resume. However it still does not answer the question which this situation bought up.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the list item in a separate entity class so you can pass it to the fragment and I would use setText(yourObject.getAttribute().toString) on your fields to reset the form with the information from the entity class.

You're already checking the data when you finish editing anyway, I'm guessing through a button click or onBackEvent(something like that) method, so if you put that in a separate function with a save button that does all this, you only have to put down a few if checks and fire the Touch from the fragment itself.

You could even put checks on the set methods of your entity that throw back an exception that you can catch and just put all the sets in one try catch.

Really though, code or a class diagram would help.

Comment: The list item is indeed a representation of a separate entity class. The save button of the 'editor' fires off the return intent.

As I said, the onActivityResult in the originator does the checks and if it decides there is a reason it is not acceptable it adds this reason to a replica Intent's extended data.

The list entity's object cannot perform checks in isolation (it's really the entire list that would be checked).

I'll have a look into making a diagram from Android Studio...

Comment: Store the entities in a new class that keeps track of the list for you? That way you can reuse the functionality of the checks anywhere you need them instead of just in the activity you are currently working in. You really don't want your checking code in your GUI background code.

Comment: Ah - OK... this makes sense. TBH I don't find it at all clear from the documentation where I'm meant to keep my objects - it seems completely UI oriented!

Comment: What - I can't up-vote an answer without reputation 15, even to a question I asked?! How does anyone get off the ground on this site?!

Comment: You reeeaaaally don't want to use your GUI to do things, because unlike your GUI you will reuse your data everywhere and you'd have to change every check in every location with every bug or change in customer demands. I would advice reading Head First Design Patterns or any design patterns book for cool standard solutions to problems like these. Imagine this, instead of checking the list manually in every gui, you can just call if(listManager.isObjectUnique(object) == true) { listManager.add(object) } and leave the checking completely to the manager's internal implementation.

Comment: Even better, you can write your own equals(ThisClass object) inside your entity and compare 2 objects of the same class with your own rules and return true/false to the manager, who then returns it to your gui.

Comment: The first point at which I seem to be able to write any code is is the MyActivity, so I'm keeping my application's data there (saving it to SharedPreferences in onPause and recovering it when need be). Where /should/ it be?

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" - I can't without reputation 20. This site is a great resource, but getting started as a contributor is really frustrating!

Comment: @user342709 - I may not be checking uniqueness, that was just an example case, but I get your point. It does not address the issue at hand though - the simplest case would be a Fragment which /always/ shows a toast when it displays :)